# Django, let decorator value be available in view function

Tags: django, django-views, decorator

I have a decorator:

```
def site_login_required(function=None):
    def _dec(view_func):
        def _view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            gets site_id. checks stuff. if else.
```

This is called in the normal way:

```
@site_login_required
def frontPage(request, url_arg):
```

The decorator finds a site_id. It would be nice to have this available in the frontPage function. Is that possible? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass it in as a kwarg when you call the view function within the decorator:

```
def site_login_required(function=None):
    def _dec(view_func):
        def _view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            site_id = get_site_id()
            url_arg = get_a_url()
            view_func(request, url_arg, site_id=site_id)

@site_login_required
def frontPage(request, url_arg, site_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

As a side note, it is useful to accept `*args` and `**kwargs` in all view functions, so they consume extra arguments instead of choking with decorators like this wrapped around them.

Comment: This is the answer, but the function has to be set up to received kwargs.

Comment: That worked! frontPage is now defined with the extra parameter: def frontPage(request, siteurl, site_id). And the view_func that you defined above is what is returned by _view.